# How to use POST in Django

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I use Django 1.11.3 and python2.7
I want write a easy message board 
and here is my code

```
<form name='my form' action='/talkpost/' method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for m in moods %}
    <input type='radio' name='mood' value='{{ m.status }}'>{{ m.status }}
    {% endfor %}
    <textarea name='user_post' rows=3 cols=70></textarea><br/>
    <label for='user_id'>nickname：</label>
    <input id='user_id' type='text' name='user_id'>
    <label for='user_pass'>password</label>
    <input id='user_pass' type='password' name='user_pass'><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    <input type='reset' value='reset'>
    <input type="hidden" name="ok" value="yes">
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^talkpost/', talkpost),
url(r'^talk/', talk),
```

talk is just for user to see the from and talkpost is for Django to get the post 
request

```
views.py

def talk(request):
    template = get_template('talk.html')
    moods = Mood.objects.all()
    message = 'Leave some message!'
    html = template.render(locals())
    return HttpResponse(html)

def talkpost(request):
    template = get_template('talk.html')
    if 'ok' in request.POST:
        user_id = request.POST['user_id']
        user_pass = request.POST['user_pass']
        user_post = request.POST['user_post']
        user_mood = request.POST['mood']
        message = 'success!'

    request_context = RequestContext(request)   
    request_context.push(locals())  
    html = template.render(request_context)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

I try using {% csrf_token %} and RequestContext But i still get CSRF token missing or incorrect.
I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: add `forms.py` in question

Comment: i didn't use form.py

Answer (score 0):

add the following:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
```

your function will be:

```
@csrf_protect    
def talkpost(request):
    template = get_template('talk.html')
    if 'ok' in request.POST:
        user_id = request.POST['user_id']
        user_pass = request.POST['user_pass']
        user_post = request.POST['user_post']
        user_mood = request.POST['mood']
        message = 'success!'

    request_context = RequestContext(request)   
    request_context.push(locals())  
    html = template.render(request_context)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

more info here:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Comment: I try to add @csrf_protect but it still say 403 Forbidden  CSRF token missing or incorrect.